# Are light-level restrictions on spawning different in the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I light up a large area of the Nether (so that the light level is >7), and give it sufficiently low ceilings to prevent Ghasts spawning, can zombie pigmen spawn?

Comment: Considering how frequent lava falls and glowstone are, I think there's no light level restriction, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this on the MinecraftWiki entry for [Zombie Pigmen](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Pigman):

> **Spawn** Any 2 block high space in any light level in the Nether. [...]

Comment: This really stinks. Zombie Pigmen tend to deal a lot of dps (damage per second) and they also tend to hang out around my nether portals, which usually makes for an almost instant death when entering the Nether. What is the best way to keep them away?

Comment: Half slab floors?

Comment: @WebWanderer : don't attack them :)?

Comment: Lighting doesn't affect MOB spawning the Nether. However, they don't seem to spawn on half slabs. More work gut can create no spawn zones.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft Wiki says "Even with no light sources around, the player can see in the Nether, due to apparent "background light". However, this doesn't count as light for other game purposes—**lighting up areas is still useful to prevent mob spawning**."

I have lit up some parts of a Nether Fortress and not had anything spawn there yet, but I haven't tested for long enough to have any certainty.

Comment: The [Minecraft wiki article](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Zombie_Pigman) linked to in the other answer directly contradicts this statement.